# mysql select query which returns sql inserts

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to select from mysql so that the result are insert statements?

I have to transfer "some rows" from my online database to my development workstation. This is always a lot of manual work.

It would be great if i could somehow:

```
select * from mytable where mycondition=myvalue AS SQL INSERT
```

and would get something like

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ( 1, 'foo' );
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ( 2, 'bar' );
...
```

This I could use to copy and paste into my local database. Is this (or something like that) possible?

EDIT: I'm looking for an easy/lazy solution which doesn't require much effort.

EDIT2: The `mysqldump --where` solution works for my question and 80% of my "real world" usage so thanks for the answer. Still it would be great if I could use complete queries for selection of the rows so that I could use joins or alter values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You need [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) utility which does exactly that.

Comment: I know mysqldump, but I'm not aware that it can use select queries. Does it?

Comment: @Scheintod Yes, it has a `--where` option like `--where="mycondition='myvalue'"`

Answer (score 2):

Use `CONCAT` to construct the `INSERT` statement:

```
SELECT CONCAT("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(", id, ", '", somecolumn, "');\n") AS sql_insert
FROM mytable
WHERE mycondition = myvalue
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort and the answer. But I'm more looking for a quick solution. (For lazy me ;)

Comment: Not sure what you expect. You rejected `mysqldump`, which is the usual tool for what you want. I gave you a query that does it the way you wanted, and you don't like that either.

Comment: What's the problem with this, that you have to list all the columns instead of using `SELECT *`?

Comment: I didn't reject anything by now. (In fact did't had the time to request anything. I just posted the damn thing 10 minutes ago. And not being a native speaker it takes some more time for me to write the answers so that I can hope that anyone can understand what I mean. (Let alone the questions))

Comment: You seemed to be saying that this solution won't work because it's not the quick solution you're looking for.

Comment: Jup.  I'm trying to reduce the effort. Currently I'm either just writing the insert statements manually if they are few or used mysqldump and copied the matching rows. Your solution is more work.

Comment: It's more work than mysqldump, less than writing all the insert statements manually.